# i tried reseting all of my data on my ipod touch to unjailbreak now stuck black screen after apple logo

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, jailbreak, ios

ok so today i wanted to reset my jailbroken ipod touch 2g because it was having some issues. i went into settings, general, something like reset, then something like reset all data and content. after i pushed that it did the regular loading bar thingy and when it restart, i got the apple logo then a black screen. no loading circle of death, just a sad lightish blue black screen. now, before that, my ipod just went to recovery mode, so i thought, why not rejailbreak it, so i did that and thats how i got it working again. then the whole reset stuff and now this. i have tried just about everything, dfu mode, recovery mode, ipsw restores on both itunes and redsn0w, and when i do that, in redsn0w, when you think things are going good, it brings up a loding bar and does nothing. itunes dows the same. please help. alll ideas are appreciated. thankyou
daniel

Answer (score 2):

Hold both buttons down until iPod-touch resets. Plug it into computer via USB. Follow the instruction in iTunes. Easy once you follow the instruction on iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Put the device into DFU mode and restore it through iTunes.

1. Open iTunes and connect the iPhone to your computer.
2. Press and hold the Home button and the Sleep/Wake button at the same time.
3. After exactly 10 seconds release the Sleep/Wake button. Continue holding the home button until you iTunes pops up a message telling you that it has detected an iPhone in recovery mode.
4. Select Restore in iTunes to download the firmware and install it.

[source](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/?enid=1034)